# How to validate input for comma as decimal separator using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am currently using this to allow users to enter numbers, but this accepts multiple dots and commas and I'd love to restrict it to a more precise number entry, because God knows the wonders that users can do.

How can I restrict it to comma as decimal separator?

```html
<input oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.,]+/gmi,'')" value="">
```

Comment: It might help to define the rules. Perhaps only allowing one comma or period and only when followed by at least one number. How specifically would you restrict it?

Comment: Use this rehex 
/^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?$|^\d+(?:,)?\d+$/gm

Comment: Do you mean you want to ensure the user can enter no., commas and decimal points only?

Comment: Hey, @UmarFarooqueKhan, this actually forces dot as decimal separator, which is useful for another purpose. Tried modifying it to comma, but I barely know programming - imagine regex. Thanks!

Comment: You're right, @showdev! This is a price field. So, I'd love to allow figures following these patterns: ```1,100,100.50,1,000.80, 100.99, 0.99```... Thanks for asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code:

```
<input onChange="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, '')" value="">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It, however, just gets rid of either comma or dot when entered as a decimal separator.